# change textbox through dropdown list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Requirement:
fulfill with a different sentence a textbox depending on the choice of an dropdownlist. but when I choose one "x" value of the ddlist, the textbox must appear empty and is mandatory to the user write something.

My problem is even I write something... When I save the form... one control that i make say me "you text box must not be empty"

here some code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        getPermissions();
        setBeginingdata();
    //in the setBeginingdata() method, the setTxtObs() is called too.
    }
    setTxtObs();


     void setTxtObs()
      {

    if (ddmotivo.SelectedItem.Text.Contains("Others"))
        txtObservacoes.Text = ""; 

    else if (!ddmotivo.SelectedItem.Text.Contains("Others"))
    {
        StringBuilder sbObs = new StringBuilder();
        sbObs.AppendFormat("The employer {0} missed because ({1})", getDrUser( ["Sigla"].ToString(), ddmotivo.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim());
        txtObs.Text = sbObs.ToString();


    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want an empty item in a comboBox, you can add one after databinding.

So the steps to follow are:

- create / retrieve the datasource
- bind the datasource to the combobox
- execute ComboBox.Items.Insert(0, string.Empty)   (or a string like 'Please select')

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/4d4462ba-f4d7-4f1d-8747-8fe63272a7f4/

Comment: hello, it possible that i did not express right. is not one empty choice in the dd-list that I want. I want that whet I choose the option "others" in the combo... automatically one textbox went empty... but is mandatory that the user write something! Thanks for the advise Robert

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand your question.  It says right in your code that if the combo box has the text "others" in it, that you set it to "".  You can't do that with a combo box that is a required entry.

Comment: I am a rookie in programming! my intention is to put "" in the textbox but if the user write something in there...when I save the form...it bring what the user wrote

Comment: Then I think I was right the first time... You need to add an empty option to the combo box if you want to be able to display the combo box as empty.  Or, simply display the combo box without trying to write anything in it.  It should already be empty when the form loads, if the user hasn't selected anything yet.  Don't get too clever; find some sample ASP.NET forms on the Internet, and see how they work.

Comment: I think when I save in the page do a postback and empty again the textbox... and I want a way to avoid this!

Comment: is not a combo that I want to empty. Is a Textbox. When I choose a specific value in the combo box the textbox empty and the user must write something!

Comment: But that requires a postback.  If you want that kind of interaction in the browser, you need to do it in Javascript.

Comment: uhmm...thats a different story then! can you point me in the right direction? I appreciate  your help! many thanks

Comment: It's going to take a bit of effort on your part to learn some new things.  Have a look at jQuery.